# C++ Grid Issues

Tags: c++

I'm printing random numbers enclosed in ascii boxes in a 6x6 grid. Having issues with printing out the grid.

Instead of having 6 columns, all my boxes and numbers are being printed out in 1 column. Been troubleshooting but cant seem to find the issue. Below is the code. Appreciate your assistance.

```
int main(void) 
{ 

    cout << "Magic Grid\n" << endl;

    int arrayxy [6][6];
    srand((unsigned)time(0));  
    int lowest=1111, highest=9999; 
    int range=(highest-lowest)+1; 

// Fill array with random values 
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
    {
        arrayxy[i][j] = lowest+int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
    }
}

// Print array as grid
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
    {
            cout << char(218);
            for (int y=0; y< 4; y++)
            {
                cout << char(196);
            }
            cout << char(191) <<endl;
            cout << char(179) << arrayxy[i][j] << char(179) << endl;
            cout << char(192);
            for (int z=0; z< 4; z++)
            {
                cout << char(196);
            }
            cout << char(217) <<endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you step through your code with the debugger, to get a grip what's going on?

Comment: debugger doesn't return me any error. No issues except that the output just gives me 1 column .

Comment: You probably confuse debugger with the Compiler.

Comment: It's because you are `endl`ing before the next column gets printed out.

Comment: @eddyiction Could you please read my answer and mark it, if that solves your issue? Otherwise please elaborate your question / my answer for future SO users who might happen to read this.

Answer (score 0):

You should `endl` after all the columns get printed out, NOT before.

This is how I fixed your code that gives, hopefully, what you wanted to have.

For the record, I specifically changed those `ASCII` to `*` and `&` to make the console result *more readable*. You can change them back to what you want those characters to be again.

```
void WriteFrontLine(std::size_t count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << '*';
        cout << '&' << '&' << '&' << '&';
        cout << '*';
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void WriteEndLine(std::size_t count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << '*';
        cout << '&' << '&' << '&' << '&';
        cout << '*';
    }

    cout << endl;
}


int main(void)
{
    cout << "Magic Grid\n" << endl;

    int arrayxy[6][6];
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int lowest = 1111, highest = 9999;
    int range = (highest - lowest) + 1;

    // Fill array with random values 
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
        {
            arrayxy[i][j] = lowest + int(range*rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        }
    }

    // Print array as grid
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        WriteFrontLine(6);

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
        {
            cout << '*' << arrayxy[i][j] << '*';
        }

        cout << endl;

        WriteEndLine(6);

        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

[image]